# rbenv / ruby-build installs fail for ruby versions 1.9.3, 2.2.0, 2.2.5 with xcode command line tools 12

Tags: ruby, xcode, macos, rbenv, ruby-build

Ruby versions less than 2.3.1 fail to install when `clang --version` is 12 or greater. To reproduce the problem, first get xcode command line developer tools version 12 via software update or wipe your mac and install homebrew:

```
# homebrew installs version 12 of the command line developer tools as well
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Then this fails:

```
brew install rbenv
rbenv install 2.2.5
```

Output of rbenv install 2.2.5:

```
Downloading openssl-1.0.2u.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/ecd0c6ffb493dd06707d38b14bb4d8c2288bb7033735606569d8f90f89669d16
Installing openssl-1.0.2u...
Installed openssl-1.0.2u to /Users/kburnett/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5

Downloading ruby-2.2.5.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.5.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.5...

WARNING: ruby-2.2.5 is past its end of life and is now unsupported.
It no longer receives bug fixes or critical security updates.

ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (Mac OS X 10.15.6 using ruby-build 20200819)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/my/qwq5ncb54svfh_qs70kjh4qc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921102602.41313.Eghhn7
Results logged to /var/folders/my/qwq5ncb54svfh_qs70kjh4qc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921102602.41313.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/reader.c
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/emitter.c
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
compiling ../.././ext/psych/yaml/parser.c
installing default psych libraries
linking shared-object bigdecimal.bundle
linking shared-object psych.bundle
linking shared-object nkf.bundle
linking shared-object date_core.bundle
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

In the file where it says "Results logged to", it reports that there were 3 warnings and 4 errors. The errors are these:

```
 % grep "error:" /var/folders/my/qwq5ncb54svfh_qs70kjh4qc0000gn/T/ruby-build.20200921102602.41313.log
./openssl_missing.h:71:6: error: conflicting types for 'HMAC_CTX_copy'
./openssl_missing.h:95:5: error: conflicting types for 'EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy'
./openssl_missing.h:173:5: error: conflicting types for 'BN_rand_range'
./openssl_missing.h:177:5: error: conflicting types for 'BN_pseudo_rand_range'
```

Gist of problem at https://gist.github.com/burnettk/04fb637c4ec18f621b2df500dbcec00e.

Answer (score 3):

Burnettk is correct about changing the Xcode CommandLineTools to a version below 12, however there is no need to delete `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, which may well cause you other issues in your environment if you use Xcode day to day.

First, open Xcode and go to `Preferences > Locations`, and check what options you have in the `Command Line Tools` drop down. If you have it available, select `Xcode 11.x` and then retry the install.
[Locations view with Xcode 11.7 command line tools selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS36z.png)

If you don't have that version available already, install the maximum version of "Command Line Tools" below 12.0 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/. When you're done, pop back to the Locations preferences, and select the tools you just installed, then re-do your Ruby installation.

Answer (score 2):

This broke with the Xcode 12 release (16 Sep 2020). To "fix" / work around the issue, f you already have `clang --version` reporting version 12 dot something, you can `sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and then go to https://developer.apple.com/downloads/, sign in with your Apple ID, and find "Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.5" or similar. Once `clang --version` is reporting 11 dot something, this should work again: `rbenv install 2.2.5`

This workaround was originally discovered by bfreezy at https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1353.